# Cannot access localized resource from app extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, sirishortcuts

I'm having trouble accessing localized resources from my Intents extension.
I've got a couple of JSON files that are localized into different languages in a framework that's shared between my app and the extension. When I access them though my app via `path(forResource:ofType)`, it accesses the proper localized version, but if I call it from the extension in the Shortcuts app, then it returns the English, even if both the app itself and the Shortcuts app are both set to another language.

The only way I can get the correct language to appear is if I change the device language - changing it just for the app or for Shortcuts doesn't have an effect.

I'm building with the iOS 14 SDK, but the same behavior occurs on both iOS 13 and 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please check Target Membership of Localizable file, make sure it was checked your extension.

[image: Target membership]

Secondly, save your app language in UserDefaults which have AppGroups.

```
static func setLanguageExtension(_ language: String, forKey: String) {
        if let userDefault = UserDefaults(suiteName: "APP_LANGUAGE") {
            userDefault.setValue(language, forKey: forKey)
        }
    }
    
    static func getLanguageExtension(key: String) -> String? {
        if let userDefault = UserDefaults(suiteName: "APP_LANGUAGE") {
            return userDefault.string(forKey: key)
        } else {
            return "en-US"
        }
    }
```